# Python unittest with TestLoader results in ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

i try to run a unittest with `unittest.TestLoader` and `unittest.TextTestRunner` but get an `ModuleNotFoundError` everytime i try to run the 'main' test file (here: test_all.py). I have the following file structure:

```
src.
    test_all.py
    dir1.
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        submodule1.py
        test_module1.py
    dir2.
        __init__.py
        module2.py
        submodule2.py
        test_module2.py
    dir3.
        ...
```

The test_all.py file looks like this:

```
# test_all.py
import os
import unittest

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = loader.discover(os.getcwd())
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

runner.run(suite)
```

And finally the structure of the single testcases look like this:

```
# test_module1.py
import unittest
from module1 import Module1

class Module1TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # do something

    def test_something(self):
        # test test

    def tearDown(self):
        # do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So, running the `test_all.py` always results in an `ModuleNotFoundError` referencing to the `from module1 import Module1` inside the TestCase `test_module1.py` (and the same in the following TestCases). As far as i can tell there are no circular dependencies. Maybe adding the current Path to the PythonPath would work, but it really makes no sense to me: on the one hand i run the `test_all.py`as main in the current directory and on the other the `unittest.TestLoader.discover()` already takes the current path.

PS: I know that putting all the TestCases in one folder is way better. But first i want to figure out why this is not working. Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue :O Any solution?